# Is this a kind of call or not? --meaning in context--

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Following is a poem by Thomas Hardy.
There are sentences 'Simple shepherds all' three times.
I think these sentences are a kind of **call** towards shepherds. However, one of my friends who is a literary critic said this means that 'like you all(=shepherds)’.He analyzes that To-morrow is my working day
**Simple shepherds all-**-means "To-morrow is my working day, like you all shepherds"
Is his interpretation possible in this context? I don't think so, but I cannot explain why his interpretation is not correct grammatically and also not good considering the meaning in context. Do you have any idea to explain this?

*The Stranger's song*   by Thomas Hardy
(As sung by Mr. Charles Charrington in the play of "The Three Wayfarers")

O MY trade it is the rarest one,
**Simple shepherds all**--
My trade is a sight to see;
For my customers I tie, and take 'em up on high,
And waft 'em to a far countree!

My tools are but common ones,
**Simple shepherds all**--
My tools are no sight to see:
A little hempen string, and a post whereon to swing,
Are implements enough for me!

To-morrow is my working day,
**Simple shepherds all-**-
To-morrow is a working day for me:
For the farmer's sheep is slain, and the lad who did it ta'en,
And on his soul may God ha' mer-cy!

[enter link description here](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/the-stranger-s-song/)--Thomas Hardy's poem, *The Stranger's song*

Comment: You can't always use grammar or logic to interpret poetry and lyrics - whose content may be emotive rather than semantic anyway. Whatever - you can interpret the text however it suits you, but I just see "Simple shepherds all" as a "vocative" interjection addressing the singer's audience.

Comment: I'd agree with Fumble, this line has metrical and poetic effect.  It is a refrain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrain).  It isn't linked grammatically to the rest of the poem. You'd do better on [literature.se]

Comment: Thanks a lot Fumble and James explaining about the poetry. Thanks again for instruction about the appropriate site.

Comment: He's obviously a hangman about to hang a boy for sheep-stealing, so his speech is relevant to his audience of shepherds.

Comment: It just means: they are all simple shepherds, and it is common in poetry to write: adjective noun all. It is a type of poetic device.